# Redirect non-www to www adding URL query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

I use SEO URL on my opencart using `.htaccess`, now I want to redirect all non-www URL access to URL with www. So I add these lines in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Yes now the URL is always redirected to www if it is written wihout www before my domain name, but I found something that I think it should not appear in the URL.

When I go to `www.mydomain.com/category` I tried to test that URL by removing the www (so it became `mydomain.com/category`) and hit `ENTER`. The URL was redirected to `www.mydomain.com/index.php?_route_=category`. I did not know what made the URL become like that, I think the URL should redirect to `www.mydomain.com/category`. I have tried to move the position of redirection lines before and after this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here is the full `.htaccess` content:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# Redirect non-www to www (I have tried to move this lines but still resulting the same)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What is wrong with my redirection lines? Any help and suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've put the rewrite for the domain too low down. Move it to just after the `RewriteBase /` and it will execute before the url rewrites do

```
RewriteBase /
# Redirect non-www to www (I have tried to move this lines but still resulting the same)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes I did think so, I have put the domain redirection lines right below `RewriteBase /` such you mentioned, but the URL keeps on changing to `www.mydomain.com/index.php?_route_=categoryname` when I changed `www.mydomain.com/categoryname` to `mydomain.com/categoryname`.

Comment: If that is happening still I suspect your browser is caching it. Clear your entire browser cache and see if that fixes it

Comment: I hope so, I'll tell you later whether it works or not.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I've cleared my browsers data and re-tested it and I did not find this issue anymore. Thank you.